# Strange Invalid Cast Exception in ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom action filter that will log user actions automatically using a [Log] attribute in my controllers. I've used this same setup in multiple applications so I know it works, but this time it's failing and I can't figure out why.

```
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext thisContext)
    {
        LogTrace(thisContext.RouteData);
    }

    public void LogTrace(RouteData routeData)
    {
        MyContext db = new MyContext();

        TimeSpan Duration = (DateTime.Now - StartTime);
        string Controller = ReadableController((string)routeData.Values["controller"]);
        string Action = (string)routeData.Values["action"];
        long? ID = (long?)routeData.Values["id"];

        LogFile log = new LogFile();
        log.UserID = User.ID;
        log.Controller = Controller;
        log.Action = Action;
        log.ItemID = ID; 
        log.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        log.Duration = Duration;

        db.LogFiles.Add(log);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I'm getting 'specified cast is invalid' on LogFile log = new LogFile().

Comment: The debugging symbols used to give you the line number of the error may either be out of date or not be correctly aligned with the code (due to inlining or other transformations).  The problem is probably the line above, where you're casting to a Nullable<long>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that, the error is one line up, here:

```
long? ID = (long?)routeData.Values["id"];
```

Check your route data. `id` is not a long. It must be a `string` or even something else.

If it is a numeric type which you store as a string then you have other options to convert it, such as `Convert.ToInt64`.

Comment: Ugh, I'm dumb. That was it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jlkmpls: Make sure you do a clean & rebuild so you get the right line indicators in Visual Studio.